# SQL Server 2016 RC1 : Unable to debug SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2016

I installed SQL server 2016 RC1 in Windows 10 (formatted and installed the OS). I first installed VS2015 with latest updates and then the SQL. I am not able to debug the SSIS packages and I get following error.

> Method 'SaveAndUpdateVersionToXML' in type 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DebugEngine.InterfaceWrappers.Sql2014ApplicationClassWrapper' from assembly 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' does not have an implementation. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

I installed the latest version of [SQL Server Data Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=620916)

Is anyone facing similar issue? Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

to run the package you might wana use this  c# solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using dts1=Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;
using ustimer=System.Windows.Forms;

namespace integration
{
    public partial class integration : Form
    {
        public integration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public int c = 0;
        public string path = @"c:\users\Package.dtsx";
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dts1.IDTSPackage100 pkg;
            dts1.IDTSApplication100 app;
            dts1.DTSExecResult pkgResults;
            app = new dts1.Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(path, true, null);
            try
            {
                pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, null, null, null, null);
                if (pkgResults == dts1.DTSExecResult.DTSER_SUCCESS)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("works");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("failed");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //
            }
        }
        public void run_pkg(string path, bool feedback = true)
        {
            dts1.IDTSPackage100 pkg;
            dts1.IDTSApplication100 app;
            dts1.DTSExecResult pkgResults;
            app = new dts1.Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(path, true, null);
            try
            {
                pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, null, null, null, null);
                if (feedback == true)
                {
                    if (pkgResults == dts1.DTSExecResult.DTSER_SUCCESS)
                    { MessageBox.Show("worked"); }
                    else
                    { MessageBox.Show("failed"); }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //
            }
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This update fixed the issue for me: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/04/05/ssdt-preview-update-rc2/